# ¿Cual es la manera correcta de cerrar conexiones y statements?

Tags: java, mysql

Estoy desarrollando mi primera aplicacion como proyecto de univ. usando MySQL con JAVA, me estoy dando cuenta que hay metodos y rutinas que no cierran las conexiones y los statements a pesar que le doy sus respectivas ordenes para que lo haga, algo debo hacer de manera correcta para que eso no suceda, que me sugieren?

ADVERTENCIA: ESTE CODIGO QUE AQUI SE MUESTRA CONTIENE ERRORES DE
             INSTRUCCIONES, PUEDES TOMARLO COMO EJEMPLO PARA SABER
             COMO CREAR UN LOGIN Y COMO REALIZAR DISTINTAS OPERACIONES
             CON UNA TABLA DE USUARIOS PERO LA CLASE DE CONEXION GENERA
             CONEXIONES DE MAS Y NO LAS CIERRA LEE BIEN EL POST COMPLETO
             PARA NO CAER EN EL MISMO ERROR QUE YO.

Esta es la clase que utilizo para conectarme.

```
package metodos;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Conexion {

private static final String DB = "sil";
private static final String DBuser = "root";
private static final String DBpwd = "****";
private static final String DBurl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/" + DB;

Connection Conector;


public Conexion() {

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Conector = DriverManager.getConnection(DBurl, DBuser, DBpwd);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error con el driver JDBC");
    } catch (SQLException exception) {
        try {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error en la conexion");
            Conector.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}

public Connection getConexion() {
    return Conector;
}

/**
 * ¿ES NECESARIO ESTE METODO?
 * Este metodo cierra la conexion, para su uso
 * el manejo de recursos del sistema.
 */

/*public void cierraConexion() {
    try {
        Conector.close();
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.println("Error cerrando la conexion");
    }

    }//Cierre del constructor*/

}//Fin de la clase Conexion
```

Y esta clase la que utiliza la conexion y genera conexiones en exceso.

```
package metodos;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class OperacionesUsuarios {

Conexion Conecta = new Conexion();
Connection Conector;

public Object[][] AccedeUsuario(String login, String clave) {

    Conector = Conecta.getConexion();

    int registros = 0;
    int usu_id;

    try {
        String Query = "SELECT count(1) as cont" + " FROM usuarios";
        Statement St = Conector.createStatement();
        /*
        PreparedStatement pstm = Conn.prepareStatement(Query);
        ResultSet Rs = pstm.executeQuery();
         */
        try (ResultSet Rs = St.executeQuery(Query)) {
            /*
            PreparedStatement pstm = Conn.prepareStatement(Query);
            ResultSet Rs = pstm.executeQuery();
             */
            Rs.next();
            registros = Rs.getInt("cont");
            Rs.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error en la consulta MySQL");
        Logger.getLogger(OperacionesLicorerias.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, sqle);
    }

    Object[][] data = new Object[registros][3];

    if (login.length() != 0 && clave.length() != 0) {

        String usu_login;
        String usu_password;

        try {
            String Query = "SELECT * FROM sil.usuarios WHERE login = '"
                    + login + "' AND clave = '" + clave + "'";
            Statement St = Conector.createStatement();
            /*  PreparedStatement pstm = Conn.prepareStatement(Query);
            try (ResultSet Rs = pstm.executeQuery()) {
             */
            try (ResultSet Rs = St.executeQuery(Query)) {
                int i = 0;
                while (Rs.next()) {
                    usu_id = Rs.getInt("idUsuarios");
                    usu_login = Rs.getString("login");
                    usu_password = Rs.getString("clave");
                    data[i][0] = usu_id;
                    data[i][1] = usu_login;
                    data[i][2] = usu_password;
                    i++;

                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error en la consulta MySQL");
            Logger.getLogger(OperacionesLicorerias.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, sqle);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (Conector != null) {
                    Conector.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException sqle) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al cerrar la conexion");
                Logger.getLogger(OperacionesLicorerias.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, sqle);
            }
        }
    }
    return data;
}

public void RegistrandoUsuario(String nombreUsuarios, String login, String clave) {

    Conector = Conecta.getConexion();

    try {
        String Query = "INSERT INTO `sil`.`usuarios` (`nombreUsuarios`,"
                + " `login`, `clave`) VALUES ('" + nombreUsuarios + "', '"
                + login + "', '" + clave + "');";
        try (Statement St = Conector.createStatement()) {
            St.executeUpdate(Query);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Datos ingresados correctamente!");
            St.close();
            Conector.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException SQLe) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error en la consulta");
    }
    /*finally {
        if (Conector != null) {
            try {
                Conector.close();
            } catch (SQLException sqle) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al cerrar la conexion");
                Logger.getLogger(OperacionesLicorerias.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, sqle);
            }
        }
    }*/
}

public ResultSet BuscaUsuario(String login) {

    Conector = Conecta.getConexion();

    String Query = "SELECT * FROM sil.usuarios where login = ?";
    Statement St = null;
    ResultSet Rs = null;
    PreparedStatement Pst = null;

    try {

        Pst = Conector.prepareStatement(Query);
        Pst.setString(1, login);
        Rs = Pst.executeQuery();
        while (Rs.next()) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " | ID: " + Rs.getString("idUsuarios")
                    + " | Login: " + Rs.getString("login")
                    + " | Nombre: " + Rs.getString("nombreUsuarios"));
            St.close();
            Rs.close();
        }*/
    } catch (SQLException SQLe) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error en la consulta");
        Logger.getLogger(OperacionesLicorerias.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, SQLe);
    }
    return Rs;
}

public void BorraUsuario(String login) {

    Conector = Conecta.getConexion();

    try {
        String Query = "DELETE FROM usuarios WHERE `login`='" + login + "';";
        Statement St = Conector.createStatement();
        St.executeUpdate(Query);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registro borrado con exito!");
        St.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error en la actualizacion de datos");
    } finally {
        if (Conector != null) {
            try {
                Conector.close();
            } catch (SQLException sqle) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al cerrar la conexion");
                Logger.getLogger(OperacionesLicorerias.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, sqle);
                 }
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Ya anoche pude resolver el problema, segun podran observar en mi codigo, aparentemente estoy construyendo un objeto o instanciando una clase, que ya ejecuta la conexion, y ademas que creo un objeto de tipo Connection al cual que le digo que ejecute el metodo .getConnection, modifique el codigo y elimine el metodo getConnection() de mi clase Conexion, añadi a mi metodo Conexion el tipo de Connection y por ahi fueron los tiros.

Para darme cuenta en donde estaba mi error, tuve que ir comentando las instrucciones donde habia metodos de conexion, paso por paso probando el proyecto e ir descartando que era lo que me generaba conexiones de mas que no se cerraban, y pude determinar que el problema estaba en mi clase Conexion.

Si hay alguna informacion que alguien quiera preguntarme seria perfecto, como ven estoy aprendiendo por mi cuenta y aun me falta manejar muchos temas.

Comment: ¿Podrias ser un poco más específico y añadir ejemplos de qué métodos y rutinas se tratan?

Comment: He realizado cambios a mi publicacion, me gustaria la observaras y me dieras tus opiniones y sugerencias. Gracias por tu acotacion.

Comment: Jamás hagas eso de armar una consulta dinámica concatenando campos (googlea SQL injection), usa prepared statements

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tu mayor problema es que el atributo de conexión `Connection Conector` (cuyo nombre debería estar en minúscula) está diseñado como atributo de la clase cuando debería ser local al método donde se realizan las operaciones de base de datos. Como buenas prácticas:

- **SIEMPRE** se debe cerrar la conexión a la base de datos, ya sea utilizando `Connection#close` manualmente o mediante el `try-with-resources`.
- Abrir una conexión física a la base de datos es una operación costosa en términos de I/O, independiente del motor RDBMS (MySQL, Postgres, SQL Server, Oracle, DB2, etc). Lo mejor es utilizar un pool de conexiones, aunque sea de 1 conexión, para que él mantenga la o las conexiones a base de datos vivas y mejore el rendimiento de tu aplicación.
- **SIEMPRE** se debe cerrar la conexión a la base de datos, no importa si abres la conexión de manera manual o si proviene de un pool de conexiones (siempre se resalta).
- El objeto de conexión a base de datos, es decir, la instancia de `Connection`, debe inicializarse en un ámbito local, es decir, debe ser declarado como variable local en un método, de manera que se puede controlar la apertura y el cierre de la conexión a la base de datos.
- Cualquier framework de trabajo con base de datos sobre JDBC debe cumplir con las buenas prácticas mencionadas previamente, de lo contrario, a la larga, te generará problemas.

Dicho esto, tu problema tiene dos opciones de solución:

- Remueves el atributo `Connection conector` de la clase `Conexion` y lo mueves como variable local en cada método, donde podrás asegurarte de cerrar la conexión al finalizar todas las operaciones.
- Mantener el atributo `Connection conector` en la clase `Conexion` **pero** no inicializarlo allí, sino que lo reciba como parámetro en el constructor, de manera que los clientes de la clase `Conexion` siempre tendrán que abrir una conexión a base de datos para utilizar la instancia de `Conexion` y luego, al finalizar las operaciones puedan cerrarla debidamente.

Sea cual fuere la opción que utilices para manejar las conexiones, tu código debe lucir así:

```
//uso de try-with-resources
//disponible desde Java 7, llamará automáticamente
//al método close de la o las instancias que se
//declaren en este bloque
try (Connection conector = ...) //iniciar la conexion a bd
{
    //operaciones con la conexion a bd
    try (PreparedStatement pstmt = conector.prepareStatement("SELECT ... ")) {
        pstmt.setParameter(1, ...);
        try (ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery()) {
            //...
        }
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    //siempre se deben manejar las excepciones
    //por lo menos registra la excepción en la salida del programa
    System.out.println("Error en las operaciones a base de datos.");
    e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    //si te lo preguntas, sí, existen mejores opciones
    //pero esta es la más básica para tus primeros pasos
}
```

Ejemplo de código *un poco más real* de uso de `Connection` y operaciones contra la base de datos:

```
//elementos necesarios en el método
//este normalmente es un atributo de la clase
Logger logger = ...;
//este debería ser un parámetro para el método
int id = ...;

public MiClase get(int id) {
    //valor a retornar
    MiClase miClase = new MiClase();
    miClase.setId(id);
    try (Connection conector = ...) //iniciar la conexion a bd
    {
        //aquí inician las operaciones con transaccionabilidad
        try {
            //lectura de la tabla "maestro"
            try (PreparedStatement pstmt = conector.prepareStatement("SELECT col1, col2 FROM maestro WHERE id = ? ")) {
                pstmt.setParameter(1, id);
                try (ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery()) {
                    //sabemos que solo puede traer un resultado
                    if (rs.next()) {
                        miClase.setCol1(rs.getString("col1"));
                        miClase.setCol2(rs.getString("col2"));
                    }
                }
            }
            List<MiClase2> listaMiClase2 = new ArrayList<>();
            //lectura de la tabla "detalle"
            //Ojo! se utiliza el mismo objeto de conexion creado
            //al comienzo del método
            try (PreparedStatement pstmt = conector.prepareStatement("SELECT id, col1, col2 FROM detalle WHERE maestroId = ? ")) {
                pstmt.setParameter(1, id);
                try (ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery()) {
                    //sabemos que puede traer uno o más resultados
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        MiClase2 miClase2 = new MiClase2();
                        miClase2.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
                        miClase2.setCol1(rs.getString("col1"));
                        miClase2.setCol2(rs.getString("col2"));
                        listaMiClase2.add(miClase2);
                    }
                }
            }
            miClase.setListaMiClase2(listaMiClase2);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //por lo menos loguear el error
            logger.error("Error en las operaciones.", e);
            //y se ejecuta un rollback de las operaciones
            conector.rollback();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        //siempre se deben manejar las excepciones
        //por lo menos registra la excepción en la salida del programa
        System.out.println("Error en las operaciones a base de datos.");
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        //si te lo preguntas, sí, existen mejores opciones
        //pero esta es la más básica para tus primeros pasos
    }
    return miClase;
}
```

Obviamente, esto se convierte en una pared de código. Para evitar este tipo de código spaguetti, se puede realizar refactorizaciones del código o utilizar algún framework que ahorre este trabajo. Cabe resaltar que dicho framework, detrás de las escenas, deberá ejecutar una estructura similar a la que luzca aquí, de lo contrario ese framework te traerá problemas de rendimiento en la aplicación.

Comment: Gracias por esas indicaciones, voy a guardar esa informacion para tenerla siempre en mente, ya habras visto que soy nuevo y ademas algo autodidacta. :)

Answer (score 1):

Lo conveniente sería que crearas un método de cerrar conexión, en el cual únicamente utilizas tu objeto.close();
Y lo llamas una vez que termines de realizar las operaciones en la base de datos.

¡Mucha Suerte!

Comment: He añadido el dia de hoy una respuesta, donde aplica eso que me dices, checala y marcala si te parece buena respuesta. Saldudos

Answer (score 1):

Para la creación de una conexion exitosa seria asi:
Un metodo donde estableces la conexion de la siguiente forma:

```
public Connection establecerDB() {
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String user = "root";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/grupoautofinprueba";
        String password = "";
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Driver no encontrado");
    }catch(SQLException ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Fallo al recibir base de datos");
    }catch(Exception ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No hay resultado");
    }finally{
        return con;
    }
}
```

Despues creamos un metodo de cierre:

```
public void getClose() {
    try{
        con.close();
    }catch(SQLException ex){

    }
}
```

Para poder llamarlo solo se debe de hacer lo siguiente aqui es donde creamo un preparedstatement que queda de la siguiente forma el ejemplo es sobre un agregar:

```
public boolean insertarProg_prod(Object _O) {
    try {
        confProg_prod objTemp = (confProg_prod) _O;
        PreparedStatement Agregar;
        Agregar = singleton.getConex().prepareStatement("Insert into prog_prod(dtInicio,dtFin,Departamento,Tarea,est_Tarea,strClave)values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        Agregar.setString(1, objTemp.getDtInicio());
        Agregar.setString(2, objTemp.getDtFin());
        Agregar.setInt(3, objTemp.getIdDepartamento());
        Agregar.setInt(4, objTemp.getIdTarea());
        Agregar.setInt(5, objTemp.getIdest_Tarea());
        Agregar.setString(6, objTemp.getStrClave());
        Agregar.execute();
        Agregar.close();
        singleton.getClose();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registro guardado");
        return true;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getErrorCode());
        System.out.println(e.getSQLState());
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para iniciar una conexion se usa: ==>  this.iniciarConexionBD();
Para definir y ejecutar la consulta SQL  ==> Statement stm EJ: Statement stm = this.conexion.createStatement();
Para ejecutar y almacenar ==> ResultSet Variable EJ: ResultSet CheBoludo = stm.executeQuery(aquilodelstring);
Para recorrer el objeto ==> while(CheBoludo.next()) {    resultadodeloquesebusca = tabla.getInt ("resultadodeloquesebusca"); }
Para cerar conexion ==> this.cerrarConexionBD();
y por ultimo para retornar ==> return resultadodeloquesebusca;

Comment: che pasos a seguir, disculparan por lo de boludo 1:

Comment: TRUD001
this.iniciarConexionBD();
Almacenar, int cheboludo = 0;
Espacio y ejecucion, Statement stm = this.conexion.createStatement();
String de la consulta SQL, String sql= "select ... as sum_boludo";
Ejecutar y amacenar, ResultSet boludo = stm.executeQuery(sql);
Recorrer, while(boludo.next())
{ cheboludo = boludo.getInt("suma_boludo"); }
BUTOOM001
Logica, try { int boludos_ar = obj_BD.cuantos_boludos();
String value = String.valueOf(boludos_ar);
jTextField_nombre.setText(value);}
catch(SQLException err) { System.out.println(err.getMessage());}

Comment: 00 --4,   String sql = "select ...as che_boludo"; ResultSet boludo = stm.executeQuery(sql); while (boludo.next()) { String cheboludo = boludo.getString("che_boludo");
nombreboludos.add(cheboludo); }

Comment: try
--{Vector<String> boludos = obj_BD.nombredeboludos();
DefaultTableModel che_boludos = (DefaultTableModel) jTable_nombre.getModel();
che_boludos.setRowCount(0); che_boludos.setColumnCount(0);
che_boludo.addColumn("Nombres De Los Boludos", new Vector<Object>());
for (String nombres : boludos) { Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>();
row.add(nombres); che_boludo.addRow(row);}

Comment: 000-- ArrayList<Vector<String>> numerodeboludos = new ArrayList<>(); Statement stm = this.conexion.createStatement(); String sql ="select ... as che_boludo, as cuantos, as valor '" +pnombre+ "'"; ResultSet boludo = stm.executeQuery(sql);
while (boludo.next()) { String descripcion = boludo.getString("che_boludo");
String bolu = String.valueOf (boludo.getInt("cuantos")); String costo = String.valueOf (boludo.getInt("valor")); Vector<String> mate = new Vector<>();
mate.add(descripcion); mate.add(cantidad); mate.add(preciototal);
numerodeboludos.add(mate);}

Comment: --- DefaultComboBoxModel boludosComboBox = (DefaultComboBoxModel)
jComboBoxnombre.getModel(); String che_boludos = String.valueOf(boludosComboBox.getSelectedItem());
try { ArrayList<Vector<String>> mate = obj_BD.suma_mate(che_boludos);
DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel) jTable_nombre.getModel();
modelo.setRowCount(0); for (Vector<String> fila : mate) {
modelo.addRow(fila); }  } catch (SQLException err) {
err.printStackTrace(); } }

Answer (score 0):

Para el manejo de recursos de BBDD, lo que hice fue crear un metodo que cierra las conexiones en la clase que contiene mis parametros de conexion y metodo de conexion.

El metodo viene quedando de esta manera.

```
public void cierraConexion() {
    try {
        Conector.close();
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al cerrar conexion", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        Logger.getLogger(ConexionDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, sqle);
    }
}
```

Este metodo aplica cuando solo cuando quiero cerrar una conexion que se ha realizado, pero si quiero cerrar consultas y conexiones, pues aplico otro metodo en la clase DAO de lo que se esta manejando en cuestion, por ejemplo, tengo una clase llamada usuariosDAO, lo que contiene son los metodo de operaciones que tienen que ver con los usuarios (login, buscar,registrar,modificar o eliminar) y al final de la clase un metodo que hace lo requerido y viene quedando de esta forma:

```
/**
 * Metodo CerrarConsultas: Este metodo permite cerrar consultas y conexion sí existen.
 */

public void cierraConsultas() {
    try {
        if (Rs != null) {
            Rs.close();
        }
        if (St != null) {
            St.close();
        }
        if (Conector != null) {
            Conector.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error cerrando la conexion!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        Logger.getLogger(LicoreriasDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, sqle);
    }
}
```

Me gustaria saber sus sugerencias, soy nuevo en la programacion, siempre me ha gustado y he estado trabajando duro para hacer que las cosas me funciones pero necesito un poco de guia.

Atento a sus comentarios [Luiggi Mendoza](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/227/luiggi-mendoza). Y esperando que marquen como positiva mi respuesta, me despido

Comment: Solo deberías utilizar este método en caso que trabajes con Java 6 o anterior. Si trabajas con Java 7 o superior, sería mejor dejar este trabajo al `try-with-resources` como se muestra en mi respuesta.

Comment: Ok, lo aplicare entonces, es mas practico ese metodo que comentas, lo q se abre se cierra en el finally, me parece bien, aunque tambien implementar el metodo sirve si se quiere ahorrar tiempo al escribir menos opino.

Comment: Ese método ya lo tiene el JDK implementado por ti desde Java 7 y es más genérico porque aplica a cualquier clase que implemente la interfaz [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) como `Connection` y otros: `BufferedReader`, `BufferedWriter`, `InputStream`, `OutputStream`, `FileChannel`, etc. Tu método lo limita únicamente a `Connection` y el otro método asume que solo has ejecutado 1 sentencia SQL para obtener datos, mientras que puedes utilizar 1 solo objeto `Connection` para ejecutar múltiples sentencias.

Comment: Acabo de editar mi respuesta para mostrar un ejemplo de ello.